# Solving non-autonomous system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Given the following 2x2 system of differential equations,

$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = 4x-y \\ \dot{y} = 2x+y \end{cases}$

A solution is easy to fins by computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the associated matrix A

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & -1 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Therefore, knowing that eigenvalues are 2 and 3, and the related eigenvectors are $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ respectively, the solution is of the form

$Ae^{2t}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+Be^{3t}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

What about if I make the initial system of equations non-autonomous? Resulting in something as follows

$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = 4x-y \\ \dot{y} = 2x+y +f(t) \end{cases}$

where f(t) can be either a polynomial on t, an exponential ($e^{at}$) or a trigonometric function ($sin(at)$ or $cos(at)$).

What is now the procedure to follow this system of differential equations? For example, let $f(t)=t^2$.

How do I solve the following system of differential equations?

$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = 4x-y \\ \dot{y} = 2x+y+t^2 \end{cases}$

Comment: Hint: Use Laplace transform.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases} x' = 4x-y \\ {y'} = 2x+y +f(t) \end{cases}$$
Note that if you substract both DE you have:
$$x'-y' =2(x-y) -f(t) $$
$$u' -2u= -f(t) $$
$$(u(t)e^{-2t})'= -e^{-2t}f(t) $$
$$u(t)e^{-2t}= -\int e^{-2t}f(t) \,dt $$
Where $u(t)=x-y$.
$$x(t)=y(t)-e^{2t}\int e^{-2t}f(t) \,dt $$
Plug this in the second equation and solve.

---

Continuing from your result of integration in the comment:

$$u(t)=\frac{1}{4}(2t^2+2t+1)+Ce^{2t}$$
$$x-y=\frac{1}{4}(2t^2+2t+1)+Ce^{2t}$$
We have the first differential equation:
$$x'=4x-y$$
$$x'-4x=-x+\frac{1}{4}(2t^2+2t+1)+Ce^{2t}$$
$$x'-3x=\frac{1}{4}(2t^2+2t+1)+Ce^{2t}$$
$$(xe^{-3t})'=e^{-3t}\frac{1}{4}(2t^2+2t+1)+Ce^{-t}$$
Integrate. Don't forget the second constant of integration.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Integration factor

Comment: You're very welcome @AnindyaPrithvi

Comment: @imranfat I did not receive your comment but you tagged me properly I think. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGq6R.png

Comment: then i reach to $u(t)=\frac{1}{4}(2t^2+2t-1)$, and this can't help me to find $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, and these have to be dependent on constants determined by some initial conditions, and $u(t)$ is not dependent on constants. where am i going wrong?

Comment: Add a constant for $u$ @JenaRayner You always need a constant for integration when you integrate.

Comment: I added some lines and corrected also the result of the integration it's $u(t)=\frac{1}{4}(2t^2+2t+1)+Ce^{2t}$ @JenaRayner

Comment: thanks for that! in the case i had initial conditions, can i use them to find C straight away or should i wait to have both constants and then find them both at the end?

Comment: Yes when you have intial conditions with the system of DE'syou can use that information to find the constants of integration @JenaRayner

Comment: what's the step between $u' - 2u= -f(t)$ and $(u(t)e^{-2t})'= -e^{-2t}f(t)$?

Comment: Multiply both sides  by $e^{-2t}$ since it's an integrating factor.  @JenaRayner

Comment: how did you find the integrating factor?

Comment: You can read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor @JenaRayner

Answer (score 1):

You can express your non$-$autonomous  differential equation in the form $$\frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}-A\vec{x}=\vec{f}(t)$$ where $\vec{x}=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y  \end{smallmatrix}\big)$, $A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 4 & -1\\ 2 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big)$, and $f(t)=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ t^2  \end{smallmatrix}\big)$. It turns out that $$\vec{x}=e^{At}\int e^{-At}f(t)dt$$ just as you might expect!

Comment: how am i supposed to integrate the exponential of a matrix?

Comment: Do you know how to compute $e^{At}$?

Comment: i dont, i've never seen the exponential of a matrix

Comment: Note $A=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\big)\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 0\\ 0 & 3\end{smallmatrix}\big)\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big)^{-1}$ and so $$e^{At}=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\big)\big(\begin{smallmatrix} e^{2t} & 0\\ 0 & e^{3t}\end{smallmatrix}\big)\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big)^{-1}$$

Comment: Also $$e^{-At}=\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\big)\big(\begin{smallmatrix} e^{-2t} & 0\\ 0 & e^{-3t}\end{smallmatrix}\big)\big(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\big)^{-1}$$

Comment: makes sense, but how do you integrate a matrix?

Comment: Integrate each component! :)